# Angular binding doesn't work inside of any tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Problem seems to be easy but I have no idea how to resolve it. I set one variable to scope and then I want to update it. The problem is that it is working in that way:

```
<button>{{number}}<button>
```

But in that way it doesn't:

```
<button><span>{{number}}</span></button>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Has your span any style?

Comment: Did you include angular.js in your <head> section?

Comment: There is no problem with styles. I can see initial value of number, but updating has no effects.

Comment: Very unlikely to be a problem to be related to the html. Can you set up a jsfiddle?

Comment: If I would be allow to bet, I would bet your are missing ng-app in your html

Comment: If you're getting the initial value of the number, but updating has no effect, that means the binding is working. Please provide a more detailed code snippet so we can observe how you're updating and why that's not working. Also, update your question to state that the problem isn't with displaying, but updating the binding. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell exactly what's going on without a larger code example. Are there any errors being thrown in your console?

Perhaps if you compare your code to this it may illuminate what's going wrong.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="app">
 <div ng-controller="numberController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="number" />
    <br />
    <span>Span number: {{ number }}</span>
 </div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('numberController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.number = 123;
}]);
```

[Simple angularjs fiddle demo of above code](http://jsfiddle.net/davidismyname/2yBrG/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure why that isn't working, but try doing one of the following

```
<span ng-model="number"></span>
<span ng-bind="number"></span>
```

See if that works

Answer (score -1):

It is working fine and please see the below the code snippet. It is helpful for you

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app = "MyApp">
<head>
  <script src = "angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src = "controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body  ng-controller="myController">
 <div>
   <span>{{number}}</span>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**controller.js**

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.number = 10;
}]);
```

Please refer the same in following link
http://plnkr.co/edit/p5N3HZnHqjLXJg3KBZuL?p=preview

Comment: why this post was downvoted? it looks OK, it lacks of some completion but I guess it is not a reason to downvote

Comment: How about adding the app declaration and/or highlighting some key areas like the need of adding ng-app and ng-controller in the  html